# Meteor does not execute created app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

Meteor does not execute a newly created app.

I just did an update of Meteor (10-29-2016) and my apps will not run.
I created a new app and it will not run:

```
F:\meteorApps>meteor create metApp
```

Created a new Meteor app in 'metApp'.

To run your new app:

```
  cd metApp

  meteor
```

If you are new to Meteor, try some of the learning resources here:
https://www.meteor.com/learn

```
F:\meteorApps>cd metApp

F:\meteorApps\metApp>meteor

[[[[[ ~\F\meteorApps\metApp ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.

=> Started MongoDB.

C:\Users\ ... \AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\runtime\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:190

      throw error;

      ^
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, symlink 'C:\Users\ ... \AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules' -> 

'F:\meteorApps\metApp\.meteor\local\.build65792

2.build\programs\.build482875.server\node_modules'

    at Error (native)

    at Object.fs.symlinkSync (fs.js:897:18)

    at Object.wrapper (C:\tools\fs\files.js:1531:35)

    at symlinkWithOverwrite (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:658:5)

    at Builder.write (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:263:7)

    at ServerTarget.write (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2214:15)

    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2322:30

    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2455:9

    at Array.forEach (native)

    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2445:26

    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2385:7

    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2786:22

    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:271:13

    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)

    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:264:29

    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)

    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:262:18

    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)

    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:253:23

    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)

    at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:252:19)

    at bundle (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2619:31)

    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2566:32

    at Object.withCache (C:\tools\fs\files.js:1597:12)

    at Object.exports.bundle (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2566:16)

    at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:574:36

    at Function.run (C:\tools\tool-env\profile.js:490:12)

    at bundleApp (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:573:34)

    at AppRunner._runOnce (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:617:35)

    at AppRunner._fiber (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:876:28)

    at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:403:12

F:\meteorApps\metApp>
```

---

Is there someone who can help me with this?

Comment: Whats your nodejs version?

Comment: Node.js is version 6.9.1

Comment: Here is what the problem seems to be: I was creating projects on a USB 2 port memory stick using a 32 bit Win7 desktop. When I repeated the test on a hard disk, it works fine.

Comment: Rats - hitting Return ends the comment again. Continuing ...|n The day before this was working fine on a Laptop with Win8 64 USB3 port. I use a USB 2 port on  the desktop. At this time, I guessing there is a timing problem with USB 2, but I will repeat the test with USB 3 on the desktop.

Comment: Out of curiosity.. why USB?